# find characters present in two different lines if they satisfy a positional relationship

Tags: bash, awk, character, ifs

I have a peculiar problem. A text file contains the following three lines,

```
>chain A
---------MGPRLSVWLLLLPAALLLHEEHSRAAA--KGGCAGSGC-GKCDCHGVKGQKGERGLPGLQGVIGFPGMQGPEGPQGPPGQKGDTGEPGLPGTKGTRGPPGASGYPGNPGLPGIPGQDGPPGPPGIPGCNGTKGERGPLGPPGLPGFAGNPGPPGLPGMKGDPGEILGHVPGMLLKGERGFPGIPGTPGPPGLPGLQGPVGPPGFTGPPGPPGPPGPPGEKGQMGLSFQGPKGDKGDQGVSGPPGVPGQA-------QVQEKGDFATKGEKGQKGEPGFQGMPGVGEKGEPGKPGPRGKPGKDGDKGEKGSPGFPGEPGYPGLIGRQGPQGEKGEAGPPGPPGIVIGTGPLGEKGERGYPGTPGPRGEPGPKGFPGLPGQPGPPGLPVPGQAGAPGFPGERGEKGDRGFPGTS-LP-GPSGRDGLPGPPGSPGPPGQPGYTNGIVECQPGPPGDQGPPGIPGQPGFIGEIGEKGQKGESCLICDIDGYRGPPGPQGPPGEIGFPGQPGAKGDRGLPGRDGVAGVPGPQGTPGLIGQPGAKGEPGEFYFDLRLKGDKGDPGFPGQPGMPGRAGSPGRDGHPGLPGPKGSPGSVGLKGERGPPGGVGFPGSRGDTGPPGPPGY---GPAGPIGDKGQAGFPGGPGSPGLPGPKGEPGKIVP--------------------LPGPPGAEGLPGSPGFPGPQGDRGFPGTPGRPGLPGEKGAVGQPGI-GFPGPPGPKGVDGLPGDMGPPGTPGRPGFNGLPGNPGVQGQKGEP---GVGLPGLKGLPGLPGIPGTPGEKGSIGVPGVPGEHGAIGPPGLQGIRGEPGPPGLPGSVGSPGVPGI-GPPGARGPPGGQGPPGLSGPPGIKGEKGFPGFPGLD-MPGPKGDKGAQGLPGITGQSGLPGLPGQQGAPGIPGFPGSKGEMGVMGTPGQPGSPGPVGAPGLPGEKGDHGFPGSSGPRGDPGLKGDKGDVGLPGKPGSMDKVDMGSMKGQKGDQGEKGQIGPIGEKGSRGDPGTPGVPGKDGQAGQPGQP-GPKGDPGISGTPGAPGLPGPKGSVGGMGLPGTPGEKGVPGIPGPQGSPGLPGDKGAKGEKGQAGPPGIGIPGLRGEKGDQGIAGFPGSPGEKGEKGSIGIPGMPGSPGLKGSPGSVGYPGSPGLPGEKGDKGLPGLDGIPGVKGEAGLPGTPGPTGPAGQKGEPGSDGIPGSAGEKGEPGLPGRGFPGFPGAKGDKGSKGEVGFP-GLAGSPGIPGSKGEQGFMGPPGPQGQPGLPGSPGHA-TEGPKGDRGPQGQPGLPGLPGPMGPPGLPGIDGVKGDKGNPGWPGAPGVPGPKGDPGFQGMPGIGGSPGITGSKGDMGPPGVPGFQGPKGLPGLQGIKGDQGDQGVPGAKGLPGPPGPPGPYDIIKGEPGLPGPEGPPGLKGLQGLPGPKGQQGVTGLVGIPGPPGIPGFDGAPGQKGEMGPAGPTGPRGFPGPPGPDGLPGSMGPPGTPSVDHGFLVTRHSQTIDDPQCPSGTKILYHGYSLLYVQGNERAHGQDLGTAGSCLRKFSTMPFLFCNINNVCNFASRNDYSYWLSTPEPMPMSMAPITGENIRPFISRCAVCEAPAMVMAVHSQTIQIPPCPSGWSSLWIGYSFVMHTSAGAEGSGQALASPGSCLEEFRSAPFIECHG-RGTCNYYANAYSFWLATIERSEMFKKPTPSTLKAGELRTHVSRCQVCMRRT
>chain B
---------MGPRLSVWLLLLPAALLLHEEHSRAAA--KGGCAGSGC-GKCDCHGVKGQKGERGLPGLQGVIGFPGMQGPEGPQGPPGQKGDTGEPGLPGTKGTRGPPGASGYPGNPGLPGIPGQDGPPGPPGIPGCNGTKGERGPLGPPGLPGFAGNPGPPGLPGMKGDPGEILGHVPGMLLKGERGFPGIPGTPGPPGLPGLQGPVGPPGFTGPPGPPGPPGPPGEKGQMGLSFQGPKGDKGDQGVSGPPGVPGQA-------QVQEKGDFATKGEKGQKGEPGFQGMPGVGEKGEPGKPGPRGKPGKDGDKGEKGSPGFPGEPGYPGLIGRQGPQGEKGEAGPPGPPGIVIGTGPLGEKGERGYPGTPGPRGEPGPKGFPGLPGQPGPPGLPVPGQAGAPGFPGERGEKGDRGFPGTS-LP-GPSGRDGLPGPPGSPGPPGQPGYTNGIVECQPGPPGDQGPPGIPGQPGFIGEIGEKGQKGESCLICDIDGYRGPPGPQGPPGEIGFPGQPGAKGDRGLPGRDGVAGVPGPQGTPGLIGQPGAKGEPGEFYFDLRLKGDKGDPGFPGQPGMPGRAGSPGRDGHPGLPGPKGSPGSVGLKGERGPPGGVGFPGSRGDTGPPGPPGY---GPAGPIGDKGQAGFPGGPGSPGLPGPKGEPGKIVP--------------------LPGPPGAEGLPGSPGFPGPQGDRGFPGTPGRPGLPGEKGAVGQPGI-GFPGPPGPKGVDGLPGDMGPPGTPGRPGFNGLPGNPGVQGQKGEP---GVGLPGLKGLPGLPGIPGTPGEKGSIGVPGVPGEHGAIGPPGLQGIRGEPGPPGLPGSVGSPGVPGI-GPPGARGPPGGQGPPGLSGPPGIKGEKGFPGFPGLD-MPGPKGDKGAQGLPGITGQSGLPGLPGQQGAPGIPGFPGSKGEMGVMGTPGQPGSPGPVGAPGLPGEKGDHGFPGSSGPRGDPGLKGDKGDVGLPGKPGSMDKVDMGSMKGQKGDQGEKGQIGPIGEKGSRGDPGTPGVPGKDGQAGQPGQP-GPKGDPGISGTPGAPGLPGPKGSVGGMGLPGTPGEKGVPGIPGPQGSPGLPGDKGAKGEKGQAGPPGIGIPGLRGEKGDQGIAGFPGSPGEKGEKGSIGIPGMPGSPGLKGSPGSVGYPGSPGLPGEKGDKGLPGLDGIPGVKGEAGLPGTPGPTGPAGQKGEPGSDGIPGSAGEKGEPGLPGRGFPGFPGAKGDKGSKGEVGFP-GLAGSPGIPGSKGEQGFMGPPGPQGQPGLPGSPGHA-TEGPKGDRGPQGQPGLPGLPGPMGPPGLPGIDGVKGDKGNPGWPGAPGVPGPKGDPGFQGMPGIGGSPGITGSKGDMGPPGVPGFQGPKGLPGLQGIKGDQGDQGVPGAKGLPGPPGPPGPYDIIKGEPGLPGPEGPPGLKGLQGLPGPKGQQGVTGLVGIPGPPGIPGFDGAPGQKGEMGPAGPTGPRGFPGPPGPDGLPGSMGPPGTPSVDHGFLVTRHSQTIDDPQCPSGTKILYHGYSLLYVQGNERAHGQDLGTAGSCLRKFSTMPFLFCNINNVCNFASRNDYSYWLSTPEPMPMSMAPITGENIRPFISRCAVCEAPAMVMAVHSQTIQIPPCPSGWSSLWIGYSFVMHTSAGAEGSGQALASPGSCLEEFRSAPFIECHG-RGTCNYYANAYSFWLATIERSEMFKKPTPSTLKAGELRTHVSRCQVCMRRT
>chain C
MGRDQRAVAGPALRRWLLLGTVTVGFLAQSVLAGVKKFDVPCGGRDCSGGCQCYPEKGGRGQPGPVGPQGYNGPPGLQGFPGLQGRKGDKGERGAPGVTGPKGDVGARGVSGFPGADGIPGHPGQGGPRGRPGYDGCNGTQGDSGPQGPPGSEGFTGPPGPQGPKGQKGEP-YALPKEERDRYRGEPGEPGLVGFQGPPGRPGHVGQMGPVGAPGRPGPPGPPGPKGQQGNRGLGFYGVKGEKGDVGQPGPNGIPSDTLHPIIAPTGVTFHPDQYKGEKGSEGEPGIRGISLKGEEGIMGFPGLRGYPGLSGEKGSPGQKGSRGLDGYQGPDGPRGPKGEAGDPGPPGLP--AYSPHPSLAKGARGDPGFPGAQGEPGSQGEPGDPGLPGPPGLSIGDGDQRRGLPGEMGPKGFIGDPGIPALYGGPPGPDGKRGPPGPPGLPGPPGPDGFL-FGLKGAKGRAGFPGLPGSPGARGPKGWKGDAGECRCTEGDEAIKGLPGLPGPKGFAGINGEPGRKGDRGDPGQHGLPGFPGLKGVPGNIGAPGPKGAKGDS-RTITTKGERGQPGVPGVPGMKGDDGSPGRDGLDGFPGLPGPPGD-GIKGPPGDPGYPGIPGTKGTPGEMGPPGLGLPGLKGQRGFPGDAGLPGPPGFLGPPGPAGTPGQIDCDTDVKRAVGGDRQEAIQPGCIGGPKGLPGLPGPPGPTGAKGLRGIPGFAGADGGPGPRGLPGDAGREGFPGPPGFIGPRGSKGAVGLPGPDGSPGPIGLPGPDGPPGERGLPGEVLGAQPGPRGDAGVPGQPGLKGLPGDRGPPGFRGSQGMPGMPGLKGQPGLPGPSGQPGLYGPPGLHGFPGAPGQEGPLGLPGIPGREGLPGDRGDPGDTGAPGPVGMKGLSGDRGDAGFTGEQGHPGSPGFKGIDGMPGTPGLKGDRGSPGMDGFQGMPGLKGRPGFPGSKGEAGFFGIPGLKGLAGEPGFKGSRGDPGPPGPP-PVILPGMKDIKGEKGDEGPMGLKGYLGAKGIQGMPGIPGLSGIPGLPGRPGHIKGVKGDIGVPGIPGLPGFPGVAGPPGITGFPGFIGSRGDKGAPGRAGLYGEIGATGDFGDIGDT-INLPGRPGLKGERGTTGIPGLKGFFGEKGTEGDIGFPGITGVTGVQGPPGLKGQTGFPGLTGPPGSQGELGRIGLPGGKGDDGWPGAPGLPGFPGLRGIRGLHGLPGTKGFPGSPGSDIHGDPGFPGPPGERGDPGEANTLPGPVGVPGQKGDQGAPGERGPPGSPGLQGFPGITPPSNISGAPGDKGAPGIFGLKGYRGPPGPPGSAALPGSKGDTGNPGAPGTPGTKGWAGDSGPQGRPGVFGLPGEKGPRGEQGFMGNTGPTGAVGDRGPKGPKGDPGFPGAPGTVGAPGIAGIPQKIAVQPGTVGPQGRRGPPGAPGEMGPQGPPGEPGFRGAPGKAGPQGRGGVSAVPGFRGDEGPIGHQGPIGQEGAPGRPGSPGLPGMPGR-SVSIGYLLVKHSQTDQEPMCPVGMNKLWSGYSLLYFEGQEKAHNQDLGLAGSCLARFSTMPFLYCNPGDVCYYASRNDKSYWLSTTAPLP--MMPVAEDEIKPYISRCSVCEAPAIAIAVHSQDVSIPHCPAGWRSLWIGYSFLMHTAAGDEGGGQSLVSPGSCLEDFRATPFIECNGGRGTCHYYANKYSFWLTTIPEQSFQGSPSADTLKAGLIRTHISRCQVCMKNL
```

Now, I want to find out the character position of all R and D/E in the three chains that satisfy the following relationship

```
Ri (chain A) - Di+2 (chain B)
Ri (chain B) - Di+2 (chain C)
Ri (chain C) - Di+5 (chain A)
```

Explanation: Iterate over every ith R in chain A and check if the i+2 position of chain B contains D or E. If yes, output the character positions of every such R and D/E pair. Do the same with chains B+C and chains C+A.

I tried to the following:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines <file.txt

echo "${lines[1]}" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) {if (substr($0,i,1)=="R") {print i}}}'
echo "${lines[3]}" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) {if (substr($0,i,1)=="R") {print i}}}'
echo "${lines[5]}" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) {if (substr($0,i,1)=="R") {print i}}}'
```

but this will give positions of R or E in the lines but not constrained by the relationship.

Comment: while your actual data may have entries that are 1700+ characters in length, for the sake of [creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you should be able to provide sample data of, say, 30-40 characters in length that demonstrate both matches and non-matches; in addition to providing the sample code you've attempted you should also update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your code as well as the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: @anubhava: edited the original post

Comment: @markp-fuso: K is typo. Corrected. The lines that start with '>' should be ignored.

Comment: @markp-fuso: Thanks for the answer. This works with one error. The relationship between R and D/E of C-A is i to i+5.

Comment: @markp-fuso: I was wondering if you could help with one additional modification. While posting the problem, I did not account for the fact that there are gap in the chains denoted by dash '-'. While these gaps are critical for identifying the n->n+2 and n->5 relationship, the character positions of R and D/E should be printed without counting them. So for example, the actual position of the first R-E pair is not 374-376 but 355-357 ignoring all the dashes before it. Is it possible to modify the code to account for this. Sorry for the confusion. It is a complicated problem.

Comment: @markp-fuso:  If only I could apply a "correction"  such that
```correction = -F"i_char" gsub(/\-/,"") 
```
i.e count all instances of dash(-) upto the i_char and substract this from pos as
```
pos=pos+n-correction
```
Unfortunately, the script still outputs as before without correction.

Comment: assume input is `---abc` where position of `a` is 4; if we remove the dashes so that we're left with `abc` ... what is the position of `a`? is it `1` or do we have to remember the original position of `4`? if the (new) position of `a` is `1`, then a quick fix to my answer would be something like `chain_i=chains[i]; gsub(/-/,"",chain_i)` (do the same for `chain_j`); pushing this change into my answer gives me `A-B 355 R E` for the 1st R-E pair

Comment: @markp-fuso: While deciding the i+2 and i+5 relationship, it should count the dashes. But when printing "pos" it should disregard the dashes. In this scheme, it is also important to output the "pos" of D/E.

Comment: @markp-fuso: While deciding the i+2 and i+5 relationship, it should count the dashes. But when printing "pos" it should disregard the dashes. In this scheme, it is also important to output the "pos" of D/E.

Comment: At this point we're getting a bit off from the original question, which in turn negates the answers you've received so far; I recommend you take the answers provided, see if you can modify them to address your latest requirement, and if unable to get your modified code to work then ask a new question ... making sure to provide a more detailed description of the rules

Comment: @markp-fuso: Agreed! Reposted [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052630/follow-up-question-to-find-characters-present-in-two-different-lines-if-they-sa)

Answer (score 1):

this can be optimized but I think works... Prints the chains compared, the position of the first match and the matched chars. Assumes chains are the same length and doesn't check for bounds.  Iterates each sequence once and compares with the other two for offset match.

Note that A and B sequences are the same, so for C-A and C-B comparisons you'll get the same results.

```
$ awk 'function charAt(_d, _i) {return substr(_d,_i,1)}
 
     NR%2 {chain[int(NR/2)+1]=$2; next}
          {d[NR/2]=$0}

     END  {nc=NR/2;
           for(i=1;i<=nc;i++)
             for(j=1;j<=length(d[i]);j++) {
               os=j+(chain[i]=="C"?5:2);
               if( (c1=charAt(d[i],j))=="R") {
                   if( (c2=charAt(d[k=i%nc+1],os))=="D" || c2=="E") print chain[i]"-"chain[k],j,c1,c2;
                   if( (c2=charAt(d[k=(i+1)%nc+1],os))=="D" || c2=="E") print chain[i]"-"chain[k],j,c1,c2;
            }}}' file
A-C 187 R E
A-C 365 R D
A-B 374 R E
A-C 374 R E
A-B 409 R E
A-C 415 R D
A-C 521 R D
A-C 606 R D
A-B 618 R D
A-B 829 R E
A-B 967 R D
A-C 967 R E
A-B 1018 R D
A-B 1114 R E
A-C 1114 R E
A-C 1224 R D
A-B 1569 R D
A-C 1569 R D
A-B 1692 R E
B-C 187 R E
B-C 365 R D
B-C 374 R E
B-A 374 R E
B-A 409 R E
B-C 415 R D
B-C 521 R D
B-C 606 R D
B-A 618 R D
B-A 829 R E
B-C 967 R E
B-A 967 R D
B-A 1018 R D
B-C 1114 R E
B-A 1114 R E
B-C 1224 R D
B-C 1569 R D
B-A 1569 R D
B-A 1692 R E
C-A 335 R E
C-B 335 R E
C-A 403 R E
C-B 403 R E
C-A 475 R E
C-B 475 R E
C-A 746 R D
C-B 746 R D
C-A 1236 R E
C-B 1236 R E
C-A 1600 R E
C-B 1600 R E
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. Although, A and B are identical sequences, I only need the C-A comparison. The C-B comparison is irrelevant. I guess I could sort and disregard the C-B comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** OP hasn't provided the expected output so I'll duplicate karakfa's output format.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { chain_id[++c]=$2                                     # save chain id, eg, "A", "B", "C"
      getline                                              # read next line from input file
      chains[c]=$0                                         # save associated chain
    }

END { i_char="R"                                           # character to search for in 1st chain

      for (i=1;i<=c;i++) {                                 # loop through list of chains
          j= (i==c ? 1 : i+1)                              # determine index of 2nd chain
          offset= (i==c ? 5 : 2)                           # +2 for A-B, B-C; +5 for C-A

          chain_i=chains[i]                                # copy chains as we are going to cut them up as we process them
          chain_j=chains[j]

          chain_pair= chain_id[i] "-" chain_id[j]          # build output label, eg, "A-B"
          pos=0                                            # reset position

          while (length(chain_i)>0) {

                n=index(chain_i,i_char)                    # look for "R"
                if (n==0) break                            # if not found we are done with this chain pair so break out of loop else ...
                pos=pos+n                                  # update our position in the chain and ...
                j_char=substr(chain_j,n+offset,1)          # find character from 2nd chain at location n+2

                if (j_char ~ /D|E/) {                      # if 2nd chain character is one of "D" or "E" then ... 
                   print chain_pair,pos,i_char,j_char      # print our finding
                }

                chain_i=substr(chain_i,n+1)                # strip off 1st n characters
                chain_j=substr(chain_j,n+1)
          }
      }
    }
' file.txt
```

This generates:

```
A-B 374 R E
A-B 409 R E
A-B 618 R D
A-B 829 R E
A-B 967 R D
A-B 1018 R D
A-B 1114 R E
A-B 1569 R D
A-B 1692 R E
B-C 187 R E
B-C 365 R D
B-C 374 R E
B-C 415 R D
B-C 521 R D
B-C 606 R D
B-C 967 R E
B-C 1114 R E
B-C 1224 R D
B-C 1569 R D
C-A 335 R E
C-A 403 R E
C-A 475 R E
C-A 746 R D
C-A 1236 R E
C-A 1600 R E
```

Comment: This works but the relationship between R and E/D for C-A is i to i+5.

Comment: @Jalan thanks for the heads-up; fixed (added the `offset` variable)

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you for the description of what each line does. Supremely helpful!